# Edit Gerrit Email Format : include project description

Tags: email, format, project, gerrit

I supervise Gerrit.

I want to edit email format. I want to include project description.

I search this site (https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/config-mail.html), but this site did not have the data of project description.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project description is not available for mail templates. Related to project info you only have "$projectName" (The name of this change’s project) and "$shortProjectName" (The project name with the path abbreviated).

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-mail.html#_mail_variables_and_methods).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Have a nice day  ; )